# Multiplied value in tableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I want to generate cell dynamically according to the number of rows in a Dictionary. On view load, the dictionary is null and is binded on the road.
The dictionary is well binded with three key-values, but when I want to create cell according to dictionary values and keys always creates three rows with the last item in the dictionary.

I can't figure it out why.

This is my code:

```
var peripherals = [String:String]()

   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(peripherals.count)
    return peripherals.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)

    for (peripheralDeviceUUID,peripheralDeviceName) in peripherals {
         cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath) \(peripheralDeviceName) : \(peripheralDeviceUUID)"
    }


    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Section \(section)"
}
```

Comment: Just  remove loop and  set textlabel using indexPath.row
cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row) \(peripheralDeviceName) : \(peripheralDeviceUUID)"

Comment: @Ralucalonescu What are the keys in your dictionary?

Comment: do you want number of cell based on values you have in your dictionary  ? like as you said there are 3 key value in your dictionary, so do you want to display cell based on number or keys ? or based on values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firt make arrays of keys and values from your dictionary.

```
    let dict = ["a": "first", "b": "second", "c": "third"]
    let arrayKeys = Array(dict.keys)
    let arrayValues = Array(dict.values)
```

then use those arrays in cellForRow:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)    
          cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row) \(arrayValues[indexPath.row]) : \(arrayKeys[indexPath.row])"
          return cell   
    }
```